# Is there a way to manually change SpriteKit's rendering framerate?

Tags: sprite-kit

The title pretty much covers it. I can't remember why off hand, but my artist was wondering if there was a way to change it for some artistic reason.

So, I'd like to possibly be able to INTENTIONALLY run at 24 fps instead of 60. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But that doesn't affect texture animations because SKAction `animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:` allows you to specify how long each frame should be displayed. Use `1.0/24.0` as the parameter to animate textures at a 24 fps framerate.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/frameInterval

I don't know if this would result in the behavior that would be desired, but I thought I'd at least mention it.

It appears, though, that since it's an integer value, it would only work in rates of 60/30/15fps etc.